# get an array into a class.property

Tags: vba

I have a class with the following properties:

```
Dim pBonds() as string

Private Property Get Bonds() As String
    Bonds = pBonds
End Property

Private Property Get Bond(index As Long) As String
    Bond = pBonds(index)
End Property

Private Property Let Bond(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pBonds) Then ReDim Preserve pBonds(index)
    pBond(index) = strValue
End Property
```

when I try:

```
Set o = New CBondBasket
   For k = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
       o.Bond(k) = arr(k)
   Next k
```

I get error `Method or data member not found`

Any idea where that comes from?

---

made the changes

marked them as public now and added initialization and byval (got me another error w/o it)

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pBonds(0)
End Sub

Public Property Get Bonds() As String()
    Bonds = pBonds
End Property

Public Property Get Bond(index As Long) As String
    Bond = pBonds(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Bond(ByVal index As Long, ByVal strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pBonds) Then ReDim Preserve pBonds(index)
    pBonds(index) = strValue
End Property
```

error is: Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray or an invalid set final parameter can anyone help me with that? thanks

Comment: This entire approach is doomed. Just expose the array as a public property scrap all those superfluous accessor methods, or do not expose it *at all*.

Comment: Tomalak, not sure what you mean. can you give me an example? I am pretty new there.

Comment: @user1266138 I think what he means is that the purpose of using getters and setters is to hide your underlying implementation. If you use getters and setters to return all your private fields, the purpose is defeated and it would be easier to just make those fields public.

Comment: You can't have a public array in a class (module) in vba, it is not permitted and you'll get an error

Answer (score 5):

You also need to initialise the pBonds array or you will get an error when calling UBound the first time:

Main module

```
Option Explicit

Sub testClass()

    Dim o As CBondBasket
    Dim k As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    Set o = New CBondBasket
    For k = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        o.Bond(k) = arr(k)
    Next k

    For k = LBound(o.Bonds) To UBound(o.Bonds)
        Debug.Print o.Bond(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Class CBondBasket

```
Private pBonds() As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pBonds(0)
End Sub

Public Property Get Bonds() As String()
    Bonds = pBonds
End Property

Public Property Get Bond(index As Long) As String
    Bond = pBonds(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Bond(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pBonds) Then ReDim Preserve pBonds(index)
    pBonds(index) = strValue
End Property
```

Comment: marked them as public now and added initialization and byval (got me another error w/o it)


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pBonds(0)
End Sub

Public Property Get Bonds() As String()
    Bonds = pBonds
End Property

Public Property Get Bond(index As Long) As String
    Bond = pBonds(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Bond(ByVal index As Long, ByVal strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pBonds) Then ReDim Preserve pBonds(index)
    pBonds(index) = strValue
End Property

Comment: error is
Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray or an invalid set final parameter

any help?

Comment: @user1266138 This is hard to read in the comments - can you edit your question with your new code?

Comment: @user1266138 I have edited the code - it prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the immediate window. Note that I have removed your ByVal - but now I need to pass a Long to the function.

Comment: thanks a lot assylias. why did I get an error when I did not add the byVal in my earlier version and why can I omit it now? this is really confusing...

Comment: @user1266138 Because I also find it confusing, I always make sure I send the expected type to functions and there is no problem.

Comment: probably a dumb question, but how do you know what the expected type is?

Comment: @user1266138 If your function is `Public Function doSomething(id As Long)` then you know it expects a Long. So in your calling code, you first define a Long: `Dim i As Long` then call the function: `doSomething(i)` and you won't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your class methods are marked `Private` if you want to expose them to automation clients make them `Public`.

(You also need parens to return an array: `Public Property Get Bonds() As String()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Public Function test1() As Integer

    Dim sdate(2) As Date
    Dim edate(2) As Date
    Dim serdat As Class_erviceDate

    sdate(1) = #1/2/2015#
    edate(1) = #10/21/2015#
    sdate(2) = #2/5/2015#
    edate(2) = #12/25/2015#

    Set serdat = New Class_ServiceDate
    serdat.serviceStart = sdate
    serdat.serviceEnd = edate

    Debug.Print serdat.serviceStart(1), serdat.serviceEnd(1)
    Debug.Print serdat.serviceStart(2), serdat.serviceEnd(2)

End Function


Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Private f_datServiceStart As Variant
Private f_datServiceEnd As Variant

Public Property Get serviceStart() As Variant

    serviceStart = f_datServiceStart

End Property

Public Property Let serviceStart(Value As Variant)

    f_datServiceStart = Value

End Property

Public Property Get serviceEnd() As Variant

    serviceEnd = f_datServiceEnd

End Property

Public Property Let serviceEnd(Value As Variant)

    f_datServiceEnd = Value

End Property
```