# How do you modify the elements in a class's array property?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have created a module that contains multiple fields, with one of them being an array of doubles. The issue that I'm having with this is that the values do not seem to be getting modified when they should be.

I have looked around, but been unable to find any examples of someone doing this. Is that because it isn't possible, or is it bad practice? Is there some way to work around this?

I have included some code below:

```
MODULE CODE 1:

Private something as String
Private something2 as String
Private months_(12) as Variant

Public Property Let Months(value as Variant)
    months_ = Months
End Property

Public Property Get Months() as Variant
    Months = months_
End Property
```

In the code that utilizes this, I attempted to access and modify a value in that array directly through the following where "lines" as an array of the objects mentioned:

```
lines(0).Months(i Mod 12) = aDoubleValue
```

So far this code is giving me no results at all. I have a for loop printing the values of each of the elements within lines and they are all blank, despite being set to either a 0 or 5

The code doing this is as follows:

```
For i = 0 To tsWork.Count            
    If tsWork(i) Is Nothing Then                 
        lines(1).Months(i Mod 12) = 0#
    Else
        lines(1).Months(i Mod 12) = 5#  
    End If
Next           


For i = 0 To UBound(lines(0).Months)
    response2 = MsgBox("" & i & " = " & lines(1).Months(i), vbOKOnly, "Check values")
Next
```

At the point where this code executes, the count of tsWork has been tested to be 30+, and after execution, the UBound of lines(1).Months is 12, as is expected, but without any values.

Comment: Your `Property Let` won't compile.

Comment: I modified it from double to variant in the declaration at the top. That should work for compiling at least

Comment: Nope, you can't assign to a static array

Comment: I managed to find a reference to this in a different question here that answers the question well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720018/get-an-array-into-a-class-property

Answer (score 0):

`months_ = Months` needs to be changed to `months_ = value`

```
Private something As String
Private something2 As String
Private months_(12) As Variant

Public Property Let Months(value As Variant)
    months_ = value
End Property

Public Property Get Months() As Variant
    Months = months_
End Property
```

Comment: more likely something like months_(i)=value , and i is also in the parameters section of the let property